# Transaction fails when using Polkadot extension

Tags: error, api, signed-extensions, polkadot-js-extension, signatures

We have a customized [substrate chain](https://kate.avail.tools/#/explorer) currently running and we are facing some signature issues ([repo](https://github.com/availproject/avail)).
This chain has custom types, custom header and an additional extension to check a parameter called appId. This extension does not add an additional signed value.

When running with `polkadot api` and a keyring, everything is fine :

```
const extrinsic = api.tx.balances.transfer(
  "5CDGXH8Q9DzD3TnATTG6qm6f4yR1kbECBGUmh2XbEBQ8Jfa5",
  1
);
const accountKeyring = getKeyringFromSeed("...");
await extrinsic.signAndSend(accountKeyring, ({ status }) => { // <-- Successful
  if (status.isInBlock) {
    setStatus(`Transaction included in block: ${status.asInBlock}`);
  }
});
```

But when signing with extension, I got a bad `transaction has a bad signature` error from the node.

```
const extrinsic = api.tx.balances.transfer(
  "5CDGXH8Q9DzD3TnATTG6qm6f4yR1kbECBGUmh2XbEBQ8Jfa5",
  1
);
extrinsic.signAndSend(
  account.address,
  { signer: injector.signer },
  ({ status }) => { // <-- Fails
    if (status.isInBlock) {
      setStatus(`Transaction included in block: ${status.asInBlock}`);
    }
  }
);
```

I don't know where to look at since:

1. The local script initialize the types correctly
2. From a local built extension, data are correctly received even with the additional extension
3. From the node I can seem to find the difference between what I receive

What did I miss that could cause this issue ?